# C Program not entering for loop, but incrementing loop index variable?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

Here is the COMPLETE text of my program, besides what has been commented out:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main (int argc, char* argv[] ){

   FILE* inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if(inFile==0){
      printf( "Error opening file, terminating program\n");
      return 1;
      }

   char* charArray = malloc(100*sizeof(char));

   int j=0;

   printf("%i", j);


   for(j=0; j++; j<100){
      printf("%c", charArray[j]);
      printf("%c", '\n');
      }


   printf("%i", j);

   return 0;
   }
```

I will call my program with the parameter `text` which is the name of a text file I want it to open. The part of my program that is commented out reads the text file into a character array, the same array I am trying to print in the for loop.

Right now, the char array contains complete garbage, but that's not the point--the point is, it's not outputting ANYTHING when it should at least be outputting SOMETHING!

Here is the output I am getting:

`01`

Somehow, `j` is being incremented exactly once, but I'm not even getting any endlines printed from within the for loop. What is going on?

Comment: for(j=0; j<100; j++)

Comment: It's clear that I have too much on my brain right now. This is such a ridiculous mistake that I'd like to know if it's a good idea to delete the question. I don't think it has much value in helping others.

Comment: Actually it helps, especially for the new users, this will teach them to never mess with order of things :)

Comment: @chouaib I'd vote to close as typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop formatting is wrong.

The format for a `for` loop is:

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT){

}
```

You have the `CONDITION` and `INCREMENT/DECREMENT` mixed up

Change:

```
for(j=0; j++; j<100)
```

To:

```
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
for(j=0; j++; j<100)
```

to

```
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

For your information

Useful syntax for `for..loop` is

```
for ( variable initialization; condition; variable update ) {
  Code to execute while the condition is true
}
```

So change your `for..loop` to

```
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
```

Also why separately print `\n` using `printf("%c", '\n');`. It should be enough like

```
printf("%c\n", charArray[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
for(j=0; j++; j<100)
```

With this

```
for(j=0; j<100; j++)
```